# Java design for multiple values scenario

Tags: java, code-complexity

I have two combo-boxes as below,

[image]

whenever i click `done` button, i get the values from combo-box and store it in a object like below,

```
public class comboValues{
private String label1ComboString;
private String label2ComboString;

public String setLabel1Combo(String val){
this.label1ComboString = val;
}

public String setLabel2Combo(String val){
this.label2ComboString = val;
}

public void getLabel1Combo(){
return this.label1ComboString;
}

public void getLabel2Combo(){
return this.label2ComboString;
}
}
```

in a controller class i use,

```
        comboValues obj = new comboValues();
        obj.setLabel1Combo(label1ComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
        obj.setLabel2Combo(label2ComboBox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
```

For a design with two combo box the code looks simple. My doubt is what if the number of combo-boxes increases?  with the above approach code will have 
lot of lines. What is the design to overcome this problem and how can i implement that to this scenario?

Comment: use some array, list or map?

Comment: I don't think you want a design pattern, as in the Factory Pattern or Singleton Pattern. I think you want a data structure, as in Map or ArrayList, or a class that wraps a data structure and provides more functionality.

Comment: Do you have an estimate of the maximum number of combo box? Even if the number of fields is large, I would rather have a field per combo box approach. Any realistic application will have finite number of form fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can have an array or an `ArrayList` of ComboBoxes. This way you can reference an arbitrary number of boxes. Your class would change to something like this:

```
public class ComboValues {
    private String[] comboStrings;
    ...
    public void setComboLabel(String label, int comboNum) {
        comboStrings[comboNum] = label;
    }
    public void getComboLabel(int comboNum) {
        return comboStrings[comboNum];
    }
    public void getComboBoxCount() {
        return comboStrings.length;
    }
}

...
String[] labels = ...
for (int i = 0; i < obj.getComboBoxCount(); i++) {
    obj.setComboLabel(labels[i], i);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I can see from your approach that you want to add more combo-boxs and against it you want to do less code in java to handle those all.

You have option of implementing Array List collection and store multiple combo boxes inside this. so every time you will not be needed to create new object and it will become dynamic.

Hope it will clear your doubt. If you have not cleared please comment.